# Format Date Month only

Tags: angular, typescript

I want format date onSubmit pass month only. For now when I submit date console.log display like this

[image]

I want change like this`{month:"april", search: "test"}`

this is my demo code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datepicker-month-picker-poc-3xfsnv)

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-group" [formGroup]="form2" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form2.value)">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date:</label>
            <input  [(ngModel)]="month" formControlName="month"  autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="date" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="{dateInputFormat: 'MMMM'}" (onShown)="onOpenCalendar($event)" placeholder="Calendar">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Search</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" (keyup.enter)="onSubmit(form2.value)" formControlName="search"  placeholder="Search..">
        </div>

    </form>
```

**Component**

```
form2: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form2 = new FormGroup({
      month: new FormControl(''),
      search: new FormControl('')
    });
  }
  onSubmit(form2) {
    console.log(this.form2.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `onSubmit` function like below:

```
onSubmit(form2) {
  console.log(
      {
        month:new Date(this.form2.value.month).toLocaleString('en-us',{month:'long'}),
        search:this.form2.value.search
      }
    ); // Output: {month: "February", search: "16"}
}
```

---

The date.toLocaleString() is an inbuilt function in JavaScript which is used to convert a date and time to a string.

`long` uses the full name of the month, `short` for the short name.

You can get `year` and `date` like below:

```
date.toLocaleString('en-us',{month:'long', year:'numeric', day:'numeric'})
```

Comment: How I want to combine with search field

Comment: @javiens Try like this: `console.log({ month: new Date(this.form2.value.month).toLocaleString('en-us',{month:'long'}),search:this.form2.value.search})` and get output like `{month: "February", search: "16"}`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to find the month index and then map it to the appropriate month name.

Here is the updated code. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-datepicker-month-picker-poc-jgsnk8

In your onSubmit(form2)

```
onSubmit(form2) {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May","June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November","December"];
    const date = new Date(this.form2.value.month);
    // get the month number 0-11
    const monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    // get the name for the month number
    const monthName = monthNames[monthIndex]
    console.log({ month: monthName, search: this.form2.value.search });
  }
```

Comment: How I need to combine with search

Comment: Do you want to console month name on while typing in the second field?

Comment: I want when console.log like this `{month:"april", search: "test"}`

Answer (score 1):

Use this on form submit

```
  onSubmit(form2) {this.form2.value.month = this.datepipe.transform(this.form2.value.month, 'MMMM')
console.log(this.form2.value)}
```

Comment: I got this error.. ERROR
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> DatePipe]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> DatePipe]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for DatePipe!

Comment: add "providers: [DatePipe]" in @NgModule of app.module.ts file

Comment: where should I combine with search

Comment: what do you mean by combine?

Comment: when console.log it show like this `{month:"april", search: "test"}`

Comment: The code I have shared with you above is giving   {month:"april", search: "test"} on line console.log(this.form2.value), Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this. We are keeping map with month number and its corresponding month. TO get the month string we can use this map.

```
 onSubmit(form2) {
        let monthMap = new Map()
        monthMap.set(0 , "January")
        monthMap.set(1 , "February")
        monthMap.set(2 , "March")
        monthMap.set(3 , "April")
        monthMap.set(4 , "May")
        monthMap.set(5 , "June")
        monthMap.set(6 , "July")
        monthMap.set(7 , "August")
        monthMap.set(8 , "September")
        monthMap.set(9 , "October")
        monthMap.set(10 , "November")
        monthMap.set(11 , "December")
        const data = this.form2.value;
        data.month = monthMap.get(new Date(data.month).getMonth())
        console.log(data)
      }
```

Comment: how I need to combine with search

Comment: On submission of form you can call this method. In the submit method variable data can be paased to api call.

Comment: when console.log it show like this `{month:"april", search: "test"}`

Answer (score 0):

I have done a small update in the code snippet that you have shared.

```
  onSubmit(form2) {
    let formData = {...this.form2.value, 'month': this.modelDate}
    console.log(formData)
  }

  onOpenCalendar(container) {
    container.monthSelectHandler = (event: any): void => {
      console.log(event)
      this.modelDate = event.label
      container._store.dispatch(container._actions.select(event.date));
    };     
    container.setViewMode('month');
  }
```

Comment: I want when console.log like this `{month:"april", search: "test"}`